# How to copy contents of a directory with the same name into another directory in python

Tags: python, file, directory, move

How can I copy contents of a directory with the same name into another directory?

Directory1\
File1.txt

Directroy1\
File2.txt

I want it to end up like

Directory1\
File1.txt
File2.txt

Right now I am trying to use the shutil.move() command but it gives me an error when the directory already exists.

Here is the code for the function

```
def move_files(source_path, destination_path, directories):
    for dir in directories:
        shutil.move(f'{source_path}\\{dir}', f'{destination_path}\\{dir}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or, you can execute shell command:

```
from subprocess import call

def copy_directory(src, dst):
    cmd = 'cp -a {s} {d}'.format(s=src, d=dst)
    call([cmd, src, dst], shell=True)

copy_directory('/path/dir1/.', '/path/dir2')
```

-a option --> recursive option

Please note the '.' at end of the src path -- this indicates we are copying all files/dirs within the src dir as opposed to copying the dir2 itself into dir1

Answer (score 0):

side note : in any given **path**, **two folders** with the same **name** cannot **exist**. The name of a folder or file must be unique within its parent directory. So

- path\Directory1\ File1.txt
- (same)path\Directroy1\ File2.txt

**Can not be existed**

```
import shutil
import os

# Define the source and destination directories (different path fo each folder)
src_dir = "D:\\code101\\python\\directory"
dst_dir = "D:\\code101\\python\\directory2"

# the same path but, two different name
# src_dir = "/path/to//directory"
# dst_dir = "/path/to//directory2"


# Check if the destination directory already exists
if os.path.exists(dst_dir):
    # Remove the destination directory if it already exists
    shutil.rmtree(dst_dir)

# Copy the contents of the source directory to the destination directory
shutil.copytree(src_dir, dst_dir)
```

The `copytree` function **creates a new directory in the dst_dir** with the same name as the source directory and copies all the files and subdirectories from the source directory into the new directory.